# jQuery ScrollTo não funciona! Me ajuda? Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: jquery, scrollto

Boa tarde,

Estou tentando usar uma funcionalidade jQuery através de um código que encontrei na internet. Mas ele não está funcionando! Vocês podem me ajudar a repará-lo?

Quando clico em 'Veja mais', deveria rolar a página até a div 'Quero Fazer Parte'.

Olha só:

BOTÃO / LINK:

```
<a href="#QueroFazerParte" target="_self" class="button white is-gloss scrollTo"  style="border-radius:99px;">
    <span>VEJA MAIS</span>
  </a>
```

JQUERY:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) { 
  $(".scrollTo").on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var target = $(this).attr('href');
     $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: ($(target).offset().top)
     }, 2000);
  });
});
</script>
```

SCROLL TO:

```
<div class="row row-collapse row-full-width QueroFazerParte"  id="row-11071">
```

Comment: Edite sua pergunta, colocando o que quer fazer e qual sua dúvida!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código funciona perfeitamente, se não colocar uma div com o id QueroFazerParte, como pretende que o código funcione? Você na tag `a` está chamando um **ID** com o **#** `<a href="#QueroFazerParte>"`, só que na div que quer fazer scroll vc colocou outro id `id="row-11071"` e o **QueroFazerParte** vc colocou na classe `class="row row-collapse row-full-width QueroFazerParte"`. Tbm retirei o **`($)`** da function que não está fazendo nada e o **preventDefault()** que também não vi o pq do uso dele neste código. Veja funcionando:

```js
$(function() { 
  $(".scrollTo").on('click', function() {

     var target = $(this).attr('href');
     $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: ($(target).offset().top)
     }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```css
body{height: 700px;}
div{background-color: red;margin-top: 700px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#QueroFazerParte" target="_self" class="button white is-gloss scrollTo"  style="border-radius:99px;">
  <span>VEJA MAIS</span>
</a>

<div id="QueroFazerParte">DIV</div>
```